# Iterating through a string array that starts with a specific text

Tags: java

I have an array, something like this:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    list.add(new String[]{"a1","12","25"});
    list.add(new String[]{"a2","33","44"});
    list.add(new String[]{"b5","3","4"});
    list.add(new String[]{"b7","15","10"});
    list.add(new String[]{"c2","2","9"});
```

I want to group elements to get something like this:

```
a
a1-12
a2-33
b
b5-3
b7-15
c
c2-2
```

I tried but the result is not was I expected:

```
for(String[] a: list)
    {
        if( a[0].startsWith("a"))
        {
            System.out.println("a");
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) System.out.println(a[0]+"-"+a[1]);  
        }
        if( a[0].startsWith("b"))
        {
            System.out.println("b");
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) System.out.println(a[0]+"-"+a[1]);      
        }
        if( a[0].startsWith("c"))
        {
            System.out.println("c");
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) System.out.println(a[0]+"-"+a[1]);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what was the result (you were not expecting)?

Comment: Use a sortable List and sort it by property `[0]` then you doesn´t need that crazy if-else ... It´s just a simple algorithm

Comment: Note that mixing array types and `List` types is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Also note that `for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) System.out.println(a[0]+"-"+a[1]);` doesn't use the counter. So it will output the same result X times.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[]{"a1","12","25"});
list.add(new String[]{"a2","33","44"});
list.add(new String[]{"b5","3","4"});
list.add(new String[]{"b7","15","10"});
list.add(new String[]{"c2","2","9"});
    String temp = new String("");

    for(String[] a: list)
{
    if( a[0].startsWith("a"))
    {
        if(temp!="a")
            System.out.println("a");
        temp="a";

    }
    if( a[0].startsWith("b"))
    {
        if(temp!="b")
            System.out.println("b");   
        temp="b";
    }
    if( a[0].startsWith("c"))
    {
        if(temp!="c")
            System.out.println("c"); 
        temp="c";
    }
    System.out.println(a[0]+"-"+a[1]);
}
```

Thanks
Kannan